# Micronaut does not map an object in a multipart

Tags: mapping, multipartform-data, micronaut

So.. I have a method that consumes **multipart/form-data**. I'm trying to pass an object named User (ignoring some fields), and user avatar file

```java
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
@Operation(summary = "Endpoint for user registration")
@Post(uri = "/register",consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA},produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Requires(bean = User.class)
public HttpResponse<DefaultAppResponse> register(
        @Part("credential")  User credential,
        @Part("avatar") @Nullable CompletedFileUpload avatar
){
    try {
        if(avatar != null) {
            Files saved = filesService.save(avatar, dirPattern + avatars);
            saved.setOid(transactionalRepository.genOid().orElseThrow());
            filesRepository.save(saved);
            credential.setAvatarPath(saved);
        }
        credential.setUserRegDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        userRepository.save(credential);
        return HttpResponse.ok(
                errorService.success()).status(201
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        registerLog.error(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
        throw new InternalExceptionResponse("Error: " +e.getMessage() , errorService.error("error: " +e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

**User.class**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
@Introspected
@JsonView(Default.class)
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    @JsonInclude
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    @JsonAlias("userName")
    private String userName;
    @JsonInclude
    @JsonProperty("user_birthday")
    @Column(name = "user_birthday")
    @JsonAlias("userBirthday")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date userBirthday;

    @JsonInclude
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonProperty("user_reg_date")
    @Column(name = "user_reg_date")
    @JsonAlias("userRegDate")
    private Date userRegDate;

    @JsonInclude
    @JsonProperty("user_email")
    @Column(name = "user_email")
    @JsonAlias("userEmail")
    private String userEmail;


    @JsonProperty("user_password")
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    @JsonAlias("userPassword")
    @JsonView(WithPassword.class)
    private String userPassword;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "avatar_path")
    @JsonProperty("avatar_path")
    @JsonInclude
    @JsonAlias("avatarPath")
    private Files avatarPath;

    @JsonInclude
    @JsonProperty("user_phone_number")
    @Column(name = "user_phone_number")
    @JsonAlias("userPhoneNumber")
    private String userPhoneNumber;

    @JsonInclude
    @JsonProperty("user_is_confirm")
    @Column(name = "user_is_confirm")
    @JsonAlias("userIsConfirm")
    private Boolean userIsConfirm;

    public User(
            String oid, String userName,
            Date userBirthday, Date userRegDate, String userEmail, String userPassword, Files avatarPath,
            String userPhoneNumber, Boolean userIsConfirm
    ) {
        super(oid);
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userBirthday = userBirthday;
        this.userRegDate = userRegDate;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.avatarPath = avatarPath;
        this.userPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
        this.userIsConfirm = userIsConfirm;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public Files getAvatarPath() {
        return avatarPath;
    }

    public void setAvatarPath(Files avatarPath) {
        this.avatarPath = avatarPath;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Date getUserBirthday() {
        return userBirthday;
    }

    public void setUserBirthday(Date userBirthday) {
        this.userBirthday = userBirthday;
    }

    public Date getUserRegDate() {
        return userRegDate;
    }

    public void setUserRegDate(Date userRegDay) {
        this.userRegDate = userRegDay;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public Boolean getUserIsConfirm() {
        return userIsConfirm;
    }

    public void setUserIsConfirm(Boolean userIsConfirm) {
        this.userIsConfirm = userIsConfirm;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public String getUserPhoneNumber() {
        return userPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setUserPhoneNumber(String userPhoneNumber) {
        this.userPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
    }

}
```

But, When I trying to transfer an object, **it simply cannot accept / parse / map it (underline correctly)** What do I get in response

**Request(Swagger)**

[image: Request Picture]

**Response**

```
{
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/reg/register",
      "templated": false
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Required Part [credential] not specified",
        "path": "/credential"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I remove `@Part("credentails")`, then it will contain an entity with fields equivalent to null.
See screenshot

Debug Evaluation

[image: Debug Evaluation]

In my research, I saw that `type:application/json` is not being passed.But avatar file has `type:image/png`. See CURL request(generated from swagger)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/reg/register' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'credential={
  "oid": "null",
  "avatar_path": "null"
  "user_reg_date": "null",
  "user_name": "User FUllName"
  "user_birthday": "2001-10-28",
  "user_email": "email@gmail.com",
  "user_password": "123123",
  "user_phone_number": "some-valid-phone-number"
}' \
  -F 'avatar=@sticker.png;type=image/png'
```

Question: what could be the problem?

Comment: Please don´t ask multiple questins at once. This is off topic on SO. Please edit your question to include only one.

Comment: I believe that you'll have to pass the `User` instance as a JSON-string and deserialize it inside the controller. I ended up with that solution a couple of months ago. BR

Comment: Might need `;type=application/json` on the end of the JSON payload. As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948243/how-can-i-post-files-and-json-data-together-with-curl

Comment: @ShingJo, I tried to put this request in postman with type application/json... Did not work

Comment: @RoarS. I think about it. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue recently.

The solution that I found (works fine):

Request handler:

```
@Post
@Consumes(value = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA])
fun createOrganisation(
    principal: PrincipalUser,
    @Body request: RequestCreateOrg,
    @Part image: CompletedFileUpload? = null,
)
```

My dto:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize


data class RequestCreateOrg(
    val name: String,

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = RequestCreateOrgOwnerConverter::class)
    val owner: RequestCreateOrgOwner? = null,
)
```

With implemented `class RequestCreateOrgOwnerConverter : Converter<String, RequestCreateOrgOwner>`